# Handling duplicates when shuffling an array

Tags: java, arrays, collections, shuffle

I wish to shuffle an array with duplicate elements. Using the shuffle method from Collections, how does it handle duplicates? I don't want two duplicates swapping each other. Thanks

Comment: `shuffle()` doesn't care about duplicates. It simply randomizes the order of the array elements, duplicates or not. It doesn't even register whether elements are duplicates. I don't understand what your concern is.

Comment: shuffle doesn't guarantee the order will change even if you don't have duplicates. If you shuffle a collection of 1 you always get the collection back unchanged.

Comment: Think of it as shuffling a pack of cards. You do that with the cards backs upwards. That is, without seeing their contents at all. So a shuffle doesn't have anything to do with the contents of whatever is shuffled, only with its traversal order.

Comment: Does it matter if the duplicates swap with eachother? If they are duplicates I don't see how it affects anything, swapping `24` with a `24` doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

All that is guaranteed about the behavior of the method is in the Javadoc.

The current implementation chooses swaps randomly, without regard to the content of the list.  The general contract states that the ideal is for all permutations to be equally likely, so I would not anticipate it ever going to an implementation that requires an element to move, much less requires that it be swapped with an element of differing value.  In general that's what shuffling is - *random* order, which can just as well (some small percentage of the time) mean "the same order that came in (or an equivalent order)".  And the `shuffle()` method addresses the general case.

If you need every element to be swapped with an element of differing value, you can of course write your own method to do that.  Beware that a naive implementation could fall into an infinite loop if there are too many duplicates relative to the size of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method for Collections#shuffle(List, Random) (A pastebin including the documentation can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/RPy93bTP):

```
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public static void shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd) {
    int size = list.size();
    if (size < SHUFFLE_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));
    } else {
        Object arr[] = list.toArray();

        // Shuffle array
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(arr, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));

        // Dump array back into list
        // instead of using a raw type here, it's possible to capture
        // the wildcard but it will require a call to a supplementary
        // private method
        ListIterator it = list.listIterator();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            it.next();
            it.set(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the overloaded variant of Collections#shuffle(List).
The difference is that you can pass your own Random object if you want to seed it yourself.
As you can see it does not look at the values in each array slot. You could try to override this method and include a check for duplicates.

On a side note: Try checking the JavaDocs for these kind of questions. If you are unsure how a method works, just google the class + method name, or use the local Java source code on ur computer.